# Is StreamController and BehaviorSubject a Stream in Dart?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have used StreamBuilder, StreamController, BehaviorSubject, Stream etc.. for some time now. But I am still confused about some definitions. Especially for this question, Is StreamController and BehaviorSubject a Stream in Dart?

The reason why I have this question is because I can find the following words/quotes online:

- BehaviorSubject is a special StreamController... (from [the API doc](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/BehaviorSubject-class.html))
- Observable is a a wrapper class that extends Stream. *(Observable is a Stream)*
- BehaviorSubject extends Subject *(BehaviorSubject is a Subject)*
- Subject extends Observable *(Subject is a Observable)*

From the above 4 points from online doc, it gives me:
BehaviorSubject is an Observable and then is a Stream. So BehaviorSubject is a Stream. And BehaviorSubject is a StreamController too. Thus StreamController is a Stream.

But if StreamController is a Stream, that will contradict with some other articles that Stream is actually a part of StreamController and you get the Stream from StreamController.stream.

If we talk about Sink, there will be even more confusing.

StreamController implements StreamSink. So a Sink is a special StreamController.

So from all of the above words, I kinda get the following result:

BehaviorSubject = StreamController = Observable = Stream = Sink

In the end, everything are the same thing... Am I crazy?

**Edited:** (I understand now. Hope it's correct)

To clarify my confusion, I think I have to understand `"BehaviorSubject is a special StreamController"` this sentence.

By googling and checking some sdk code, I think I understand that BehaviorSubject is a special StreamController, **but not vice versa**. That will solve my confusion. BehaviorSubject extends Subject, and Subject implements StreamController. Thus `"BehaviorSubject is a special StreamController"` is correct. But I can't say StreamController is a BehaviorSubject. Thus I can't say StreamController is a Stream even if BehaviorSubject is actually a Stream.

I hope what I understand above is correct.

Comment: BehaviorSubject is a special StreamController, but not vice versa

Answer (score 9):

A `StreamController` is a `StreamController`.
It does not extend anything. So it is not any of `Observable`, `Stream`, `BehaviorSubject` or `Sink`.

It does **implement** `Sink` as you said and thus allow you to add data on it directly, i.e. use `streamController.add` as well as `streamController.sink.add`. This data is then passed onto the `Stream` that each controller carries.

`BehaviorSubject` is not actually part of the standard library and just a fancy addition to streams from [`rxdart`](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/rxdart). It allows you to access the latest value at any time directly.

Answer (score 4):

Not crazy at all, A stream is just like a pipe that take in data as a sink and give  it back as a stream, while StreamController is just use to control the the stream. i hope this is helpful

Answer (score 1):

`Observable` class is deprecated in `rxdart 0.23.1`

`Observable` can be replaced by `Stream`

[rxdart-changelog](https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart/changelog)